# The loss of the internet connection due to the network bridge configuration

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I'm following the tutorial on how to set up KVM on Ubuntu 18.04.

There is a line saying : "Before you can dive in and start making virtual machines, you're going to need to set up a network bridge."

And so I follow along, however do I need to set up a network bridge ?

Anyways.

I do the recommended things. 
I find out what is my current interface  :

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: p1p1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 24:b6:fd:59:e7:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 84:4b:f5:1b:0a:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.140/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute wlp9s0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::902b:af87:1a9:a671/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:89:7d:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:89:7d:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Then I modify the /etc/network/interfaces file

The original file before modifictions looks like that :

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

After modifications, the recommended stuff from tutorial I added to file, it looks like that :

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback 
iface wlp9s0 inet manual
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports wlp9s0
```

After modifying the file I do the reboot and I have no internet connection. 
Here is how ip a command looks like after the reboot :

```
ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: p1p1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 24:b6:fd:59:e7:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 84:4b:f5:1b:0a:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether ae:cc:72:45:90:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 169.254.8.154/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link br0:avahi
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::accc:72ff:fe45:9092/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:89:7d:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:89:7d:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Where is the mistake here ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having trouble due to conflicts in you network configuration.  Since Ubuntu 17.10 by default Ubuntu uses Netplan. The configurations are kept in '/etc/netplan/*.yaml files'.

Depending on the Ubuntu version you are using, server or desktop, the configurations are handled by network renderers either networkd or NetworkManager by default.

NetworkManager(Ubuntu Desktop) config files are in '/etc/NetworkManager/'. The networkd(Ubuntu Server) config files are in '/etc/systemd/network/'.

You should restore the '/etc/network/interfaces' file to default and create a bridge connection using Netplan(Server) or NetworkManger(Desktop). Be sure to backup any files before you make any changes so you can easily restore to original working configuration.

Here are some links to documentation and answers to help you.

[NetworkManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager)

[Netplan](https://netplan.io/)

[How to Use the Netplan Network Configuration Tool on Linux](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/how-use-netplan-network-configuration-tool-linux/)

[How to add network bridge with nmcli (NetworkManager) on Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-add-network-bridge-with-nmcli-networkmanager-on-linux/)

---

### Netplan Bridged Example

```
#01-network-manager-all.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        - enp3s0
```

---

### NetworkManager

```
$ nmcli con show
$ nmcli connection show --active 
$ sudo nmcli con add ifname br0 type bridge con-name br0
$ sudo nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname eno1 master br0
$ nmcli connection show
$ sudo nmcli con down "Wired connection 1"
$ sudo nmcli con up br0
$ nmcli con show
```

Comment: Thank you @da_kingpin, you're a star ! :]